# How to bind Reactive FormArray on Async Data?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a form which will bind formArray using async data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.bindNewRequestControls();
  }

  bindNewRequestControls() {
    this.alertSuppressionRequestForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      formAppplications: this.formbuilder.array(this.dynamicControls())
    })
  }

  dynamicControls() {
    const _dynamiccontrols = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      _dynamiccontrols.push(this.formbuilder.group({
        selectrow: [''],
        todate: [''],
        fromdate: [''],
        changeRequest: [''],
        justification: ['']
      }))
    }
    return _dynamiccontrols;
  }
```

now, in this above code **this.data** is the data which will be getting added asyncronously, like this

```
applicationDropdownChange(data?: string) {
    this.service.post('url', 'request')
      .subscribe(success => {
      this.data=success;
      });
  }
```

now when i bind this variable with the async data, i get an error like this

[image]

but when i pass data statically on the ngOninit() event, everythign works fine, how can i overcome this? thank you

Comment: you need call to bindNewRequestControls INSIDE "subscribe" function, not in ngOnInit

Comment: Have you tried `<form *ngIf="data">` in your template?

Comment: @Eliseo when i called the bindNewRequestControls  method from inside the subscribe, it works and all the functionality as well but i get an console error, like this
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Comment: use in your .htm  `<form *ngIf="alertSuppressionRequestForm" [formGroup]="alertSuppressionRequestForm"...>`. The "*ngIf" make that at first, when you has no  formGroup, not show it and don't give you the error